# Script uses same name everytime for multiple requests instead of using different name per request

Tags: java, scala, gatling

I am creating a gatling script which takes names in StringBody. Name should be unique everytime so I have to generate different random names. Here below script generates different names.

For single user it works fine. For multiple users it generates multiple random names but request with **SAME NAME everytime** instead of using different name on every requests.

Like if I use userCount = 5, it will generates 5 different strings but unfortunately it request with one same string everytime in stringBody. I want 5 requests with different names. Can anyone please help me? Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util.Random

class myTerm extends Simulation {

    val scenarioRepeatCount = Integer.getInteger("scenarioRepeatCount", 1).toInt
    val userCount = Integer.getInteger("userCount", 5).toInt
    val TID = System.getProperty("TID", "13203462112")

    // Methods for random char generator
    def randomAlpha(length: Int): String = {
        val chars = ('a' to 'z') ++ ('a' to 'z')
        randomStringFromCharList(length, chars)
    }

    def randomStringFromCharList(length: Int, chars: Seq[Char]): String = {
        val sb = new StringBuilder
        for (i <- 1 to length) {
        val randomNum = util.Random.nextInt(chars.length)
        sb.append(chars(randomNum))
        }
        sb.toString
    }

    val httpProtocol = http
        .connection("""keep-alive""")
        .contentTypeHeader("""application/json""")

    val scn = scenario("Create")
    .repeat (scenarioRepeatCount) {
        exec(http("Create with random names")
                .post(s"""http://someurl/api/thri/$TID/terms""")
                .body(StringBody("""{"term": """" + randomAlpha(7) + """"}""")) // Here randomAlpha(7) creates a string with 7 alphabates
            )
        }
    setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(userCount))).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

EDIT 2:

I am facing issues with fetching assetId, it prints 'assetId' instead of value. Please have a look below code.

```
.foreach("${IdList}", "assetid") {
        exec(http("Load_Asset_Details")
        .get(s"""$addTagsUrl/am/images/loader.svg""")
        .resources(
        http("Actions_request")
        .post(s"""$addTagsUrl/am/actions""")
        .headers(headers_52)
        .body(StringBody("""{"objects":[{"id":${assetid},"resource":"asset"}]}""")),
        http("variant_request")
        .get(s"""$addTagsUrl/am/variants%3BresourceType=asset""")
        .headers(headers_6),
        http("Keyframe_request")
        .get(s"""$addTagsUrl/am/$${assetid}/keyframes""")
        .headers(headers_6)))

    .exec(http("Add Tags")
        .post(s"""$addTagsUrl/am/$${assetid}/tags""")
        .headers(headers_52)

    //This prints value of assetid but does not generates random numbers    
          //.body(StringBody(s"""{"objectId":$${assetid},"objectType":"asset","name": "$tagName$randomNumber","accountId":4,"userId":5}"""))

    // This generates random numbers but Doesnt assetid it prints "assetid" text instead of value
    .body(StringBody(_ => """{"objectId":"""" + assetid + """" ,"objectType":"asset","name": """ + tagName + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(10, 80) + ""","accountId":4,"userId":5}"""))
        )   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work to set and retrieve user Id (I am using `java.util.UUID` here):

```
scenario("add userId to request")
    .exec(_.set("userId", UUID.randomUUID().toString())
    .exec(
        http("getCredentials ${userId}")
        .get("/cred")
        // [...]
    )
```

Naturally the userId generation should not be inside a `repeat()` or any other loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. It worked but stuck in another situation. I am facing issues with fetching assetId, it prints 'assetId' instead of value. Please see edited question.